# foreign key returning null in a one to many relationship

Tags: database, sequelize.js

I am trying to create a channelentry that belongs to channels and users. I am getting a foreign key for the user column but im having trouble getting a foreign key for my channel.

```
router.post("/create/:id", validateJWT, async (req, res) => {
const {entry} = req.body.channelentry
 const channelMessage = {
     entry,
     userId: req.user.id
 }
 try {
  const currentChannelId =  await models.ChannelModel.findOne({
       where: {
           id: req.params.id
       }
   })
   const newChannel = await models.ChannelEntryModel.create(channelMessage, currentChannelId);
   res.status(200).json(newChannel)
} catch (err) {
   res.status(500).json({error: err})
}
```

i did find one way to fill the channel foreign key but that also has issues.

I did a findOrCreate method that does return a foreign key but if there is already an entry that matches it will not create a new entry.

```
router.post("/create/:id", validateJWT, async (req, res) => {
const {entry} = req.body.channelentry
 try {
   const newChannel = await models.ChannelEntryModel.findOrCreate({
                where: {
                    entry,
                    userId: req.user.id,
                    channelId: req.params.id
                }
            })
 
   res.status(200).json(newChannel)
} catch (err) {
   res.status(500).json({error: err})
}
```

is there something i am missing in the first approach or is there a way to create a new entry even if an entry matches for a findOrCreate method.

Answer (score -1):

nvm... i got it to work xD. just needed to pass req.params.id into channelmessage.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).